# Print Variable Into JSON NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, rest, api

I'm working to developed API with NodeJS. I got undefined value when I 
print the value.

Here's my code:

```js
const modelMateris = require("../models/materi");

var Home = {
  getHome: (req, res, next) => {

    const materisAsync = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      modelMateris.find({},(err, res) => {
        if(err) reject(err);
        resolve(res);
      });
    });

    var a = materisAsync
      .then(res => console.log(res))
      .catch(res => console.log(err));

    res.send({code:1000, materis:a });
  }
}

module.exports = Home;
```

I just want to show the output of var A into RESTAPI. So how to print it in NodeJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
materisAsync
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
        const a = res
        res.send({code:1000, materis: res});
    })
    .catch(res => console.log(err));
```

As you are using then block the promise resolved value will be coming in the then block and be assigned to a variable, you can use async await in place of then block, as shown below.

```
var Home = {
        getHome: async (req, res, next) => {
            try {
                const materisAsync = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    modelMateris.find({}, (err, res) => {
                        if (err) reject(err);
                        resolve(res);
                    });
                });

                const a = await materisAsync
                const b = await secondApicall // like this you can call multiple api

                res.send({ code: 1000, materis: a});
            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: actually i want to create multiple API coming from different db model. so i declare variable to handle it. btw ur code still not working cause i run it with postman

Comment: For calling multiple api you can use async await, i have edited the code, please find the same.